# Is there a way to create a S3 connection with a sessions token?

Tags: python, amazon-s3

In `boto` and `S3` modules the S3 connection constructor takes the access key and the secret key. Is there a connection object that exists that also takes a session token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hadn't currently been implemented in `boto` but has been now and will be in version 2.1 or is available now if you check out the source from github.

You can use a session token by passing the token with the key word argument `security_token` to `boto.connect_s3`. I think the session token will be implemented elsewhere soon as well.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but it's one of the few results on Google. So here is how you can do this (at least with Boto 2.22.1):

```
conn = S3Connection(
    aws_access_key_id=<access>,
    aws_secret_access_key=<secret>,
    security_token=<token>.,
)
```